# How to assert the contents of a copied and pasted row using XCTAssert

Tags: swift, assert, xctest, assertion, xcuitest

**What I'm doing.**

1. I am creating a paragraph block/row
2. Filling that row with random text
3. Copying and pasting that row using the built-in `copy` and `paste` block feature
4. Then trying to assert the newly pasted row to check it matches the text in the first block of the text

Currently how I am asserting, but failing:

```
func confirmPastedParagraphBlock() -> BlockEditorScreen {
    XCTAssert(pastedBlockView.isEqual(copiedBlockView))

    return self
}
```

I am also using the following objects:

```
let copiedBlockView = XCUIApplication().otherElements["Paragraph Block. Row 1."]
let pastedBlockView = XCUIApplication().otherElements["Paragraph Block. Row 2."]
```

I know how I want to assert, but just not sure where I am going wrong - it fails at the `confirmPastedParagraphBlock` step when it's called.

Answer (score 0):

`XCUIApplication().otherElements["Paragraph Block. Row 1."]` Returns an XCUIElement.

What you want to assert is the content of those elements.

If you look into `XCUIElementAttributes` you have a few properties at your disposal.

```swift
 /** The raw value attribute of the element. Depending on the element, the actual type can vary. */
    var value: Any? { get }

    /** The title attribute of the element. */
    var title: String { get }

    /** The label attribute of the element. */
    var label: String { get }
```